# Set theory exam question on infinite union of relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-theory, recurrence-relations, relations, problem-solving

Let $R$ be any relation over $\mathbb Z$ (the integers). Let $R_n $ be the set of all relations $ R $ (over the integers) such that $n$ is natural, by:

$
R_0:= R$.

$R_{n+1}:= R_n \cup (R_n ◦ R_n)$.

$R_∞=\bigcup\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} R_{n}$.

(couldn't figure out how to write the index correctly so i just wrote it regularly).

Show that for every natural number $n$, exist a relation $ R$ (over the integers) such that;  $R_{n+1}=R_∞  $
and $R_n≠R_∞$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each stage makes it so that if $xR_ny$ and $yR_nz$ then $xR_{n+1}z$. Intuitively, you can think of this as $(x,z)$ being in the relation $R_{n+1}$ if there is a path of lenth $\le 2$ between $x$ and $z$ in $R_n$. Or length $\le 4$ in $R_{n-1}$, length $\le 8$ in $R_{n-2}$ etc. So $(x,z)$ is in $R_n$ if there is a path of length $\le 2^n$ in $R_0$.

So what this comes down to is finding a relation where all $x$ and $z$ that can be connected by a path are connected by a path of length $2^{n+1}$, but some of them need a path longer then $2^n$. Can you think of a relation like that for a given $n$?

You also don't need the relation you first think of to be on the integers. If you make it on any set smaller than the integers, you can fit it into a relation on the integers so that it has the same property.

Comment: Firstly thank you for helping me out and for this very detailed explanation. The first part of your explanation, is something that can comfortably say that I understand and in fact I even got there myself. So the problematic part for me in this proof isn’t understanding the relation, but rather the given condition. When i sit down to try and solve it i get stuck asking myself “What is the meaning behind these equality an inequality?”, “And how do they project over the relation?”. and i cant seem to be progressing in that direction. Thank you so much for the help hoping to hear from you soon.

Comment: @userא0
I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by

>  “What is the meaning behind these equality an inequality?”, “And how do they project over the relation?”

Comment: I was just trying to emphasize what went through my mind when I was trying to solve this problem. I think i don't fully understand the meaning of finding a relation R under the following requirements; Rn+1=R∞ and Rn≠R∞. (This is what i meant by saying "equality and inequality"). Thanks again.

Comment: @userא0

$R_\infty$ is what you get by making $x$ and $z$ connected if there is a path of any length connecting them, no matter how long. $R_n$ is making $x$ and $z$ connected if there is a path of length $2^n$. So $R_n \ne R_\infty$ means there are some $x$ and $z$ which do have a path connecting them, but don't hve any path of length $\le 2^n$ connecting them. Similarly, $R_{n+1} = R_\infty$ means every $x$ and $y$ which can be connected by a path can be connected by a path of length $\le 2^{n+1}$.

Comment: alright i think i finally got it. Thank you so much for the help :)